# Get parent action from child action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am crating pager partial view, which take one page count parameter from parent view, and render paging numbers inside view

```
//List.cshtml

bla bla data here
@Html.Action("Index", "Pager", new {pageCount = 120})
```

now inside pagers view, I want to repeat parent action with new page number... I want page buttons inside my partial view, to just repeat parent actions with appreciate page parameter, but when I do a call  `Url.Action(null, new {page = curPage-1}` MVC tracts null as an action of partial view, but not parent, and throw exception that partial action can't be called directly

```
<a title="go to page @(curPage-1)" rel="prev" href="@Url.Action(null, new {page = curPage-1})">
    <span class="page-numbers prev">prev </span>
</a>
```

I mean, I want to have `href = domain/list/id?page=2`, instead of `domain/pager/index?page=2`

Are there any way to repeat partial action's parent action with new additional parameter?

Comment: would you mind calling a action from partial view and then redirecting to the index action from this?  And have you tried the syntax Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName", new {page = curPage-1}

Comment: Calling an action from partial and redirecting might be a solution, but I prefer it to work for different parent actions since I want to use it for all views that support paging...

Comment: Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName", new {page = curPage-1}  must work . have you tried it?

Comment: The problem is that actionname and controllername are different for different parent views...one way is to pass that to partial view, but not sure if i can get that automaticaly

Comment: Lemme be clear with this. You have a Main/parent View with 1 partial view for it.. Like wise you have many Parent View with 1 partial view for each. correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I have several vews that have a paging, i want to use same pager partial for all of this views each of which have different controller, and i always wants my pager to redirect to that parent controller... Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in your parent view

```
@{
 ViewData["ActionName"] = "MyACtion";
 ViewData["ControllerName"] = "MyControllerACtion";
}
```

then call your Partial View.
Here you can retrieve the values from the ViewData

inside partial view

```
@Html.Action(ViewData["ActionName"], ViewData["ControllerName"], new {pageCount = 120})
```

OR

```
@{
 var action = ViewData["ActionName"];
var controller = ViewData["ControllerName"];
}

@Html.Action(@action, @controller, new {pageCount = 120})
```

Comment: Does this make sense?

Comment: sure, thanks for response, so do you mean the only way to get parent controller action, is to pass as param?

Comment: Yes but this is ViewData not param this is the only way you can communicate between 2 views without posting back to Server(Action method), As your partial view must use Controller & action names dynamically the only way would be by passing them as ViewData so that the partial view can use them.

Comment: I guess the other way would be to pass params to controller action directly? like new {pageCount = 120, controller ="List", Action = "Index"} ?

Comment: But where are you passing these from?? from Parent to Partial?

Comment: from parent view to partial action, than I can pass from partial action to partial view from model right?

Comment: Hmmm yes this can be done but again after passing from Partial Action to partial view You will end up in same thing as to retrieve value and put in the syntax of @Html.Action